# windows form app sending strings

Tags: c#, winforms, networking, asynchronous, tcp

I made a tcp/ip chat windows form application and it works just fine but I want to make the application to send the text automatically I don't want the user to click the send button like a live streaming!

and I am using Asynchronous connection.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;


using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;

namespace Chat
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Socket sck;
        EndPoint epLocal, epRemote;


        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            sck = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
            sck.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);
            textBox1.Text = GetLocalIP();//this is where the application is running IP address
            //textBox5.Text = GetLocalIP();
        }

        private string GetLocalIP()
        { 
            IPHostEntry host;
            host = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
            foreach (IPAddress ip in host.AddressList)
            {
                if(ip.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
                {  
                    return ip.ToString();
                }
            }

            return "127.0.0.1"; //here we put the android device's IP

        }

        private void MessageCallBack(IAsyncResult aResult)
        {
            try {

                int size = sck.EndReceiveFrom(aResult, ref epRemote);

                if(size>0)
                {
                    byte[] receivedData = new byte[1464];
                    receivedData = (byte[])aResult.AsyncState;

                    ASCIIEncoding eEncoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
                    string receivedMessage = eEncoding.GetString(receivedData);
                    //b3deen bntba3 el msg bs b7aletna bdna n5li el touch active.
                    listBox1.Items.Add("Sender:" + receivedMessage);
                }

                byte[] buffer = new byte[1500];
                sck.BeginReceiveFrom(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, ref epRemote, new AsyncCallback(MessageCallBack), buffer);

            }
            catch (Exception exp)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(exp.ToString());
            }
        }


        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

                try
                {
                    //binding the message
                    epLocal = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.9"), Convert.ToInt32("80"));
                    sck.Bind(epLocal);
                    //hoon el address ta3 el mobile 
                    epRemote = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.9"), Convert.ToInt32("81"));//texbox5 bn7at el ip ta3 el android wl txt el tani ta3 le port
                    //hoon bn3ml connect network
                    sck.Connect(epRemote);

                    byte[] buffer = new byte[1500];
                    sck.BeginReceiveFrom(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, ref epRemote, new AsyncCallback(MessageCallBack), buffer);

                    button1.Text = "Connected";
                    button1.Enabled = false;
                    button2.Enabled = true;
                    textBox3.Focus();

                    //trying to live sending




                }


                catch (Exception exp)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(exp.ToString());
                }

        }
       private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
          try
            {
                System.Text.ASCIIEncoding enc = new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding();
                byte[] msg = new byte[1500];
                msg = enc.GetBytes(textBox3.Text);

                sck.Send(msg);
                listBox1.Items.Add("YOU:" + textBox3.Text);


            }catch (Exception exp)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(exp.ToString());
            }
           // Close();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Post some code. Do you want to send the text as the user types?

Comment: yes yes yes :D I will add the code just a sec @Abhishek

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey all I just find out what to do I wanted to send each string when its written so what i did I just handled the event for the textbox it self so when ever its changed it will send it right away :D good luck all :)

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you want to send the text the user entered as he finished to type it. Even if I'd say this is a bad idea because it will confuse your users, you could add a timer which is counting the time since the user's last key stroke and if a given time was passed (let's say 5 secs), it invokes the method your button click is invoking as well to send the string.

Comment: I want to send the string as its being typed, it is not for a usual chat application its for sending sensors data.